# Angular Calling a function when parameter values change

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to call a function from a component that is already loaded when navigating to the same route and only parameter values change. I have urls that look like `BASE_URL/param/site` and I need to call a function when this param changes. I tried subscribing to activatedRoute.params, but not working:

```
constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        activatedRoute.params.subscribe(val => this.myfunction())
    }
```

I'm a beginner, sorry if it's a silly question, but I've been testing for hours without result

**Update**

I've been asked to share the routing config:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DefineCourseComponent } from "./components/define-course/define-course.component";
import { SelectContentComponent } from "./components/select-content/select-content.component";
import { OrganizeContentComponent } from "./components/organize-content/organize-content.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/create', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'create', component: DefineCourseComponent },
    { path: ':courseID/define', component: DefineCourseComponent },
    { path: ':courseID/select', component: SelectContentComponent },
    { path: ':courseID/organize', component: OrganizeContentComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

CourseID is the param that changes

Comment: actually that's correct, can you share your routering config as well?

Comment: Could please share your url route confi? better if you can mock it on stackblitz

Comment: and in which component you are subscribing to the params change?

Comment: A component named navigation-component, that is always loaded, and inside this component I have the router-outlet

Comment: I can understand, it will not work, because the params change is only available at the component where the route is connected.

Comment: But how should I do it?